# Could not find HTTP response object for this identifier

Tags: apache-nifi

I am using the below Nifi processors

```
HTTPRequestHandler -> Some custom processors in between -> HTTPResponseHandler
```

Custom processors are used for doing some transformations.

In the HTTPResponseHandler processor i am getting

`Flowfile had an HTTP.Context.identifier of true but Could not find HTTP response object for this identifier`

Can anyone please help me on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to resolve the error **HTTP.Context.identifier of true but Could not find HTTP response object for this identifier**.

It was due to the Request Expiration property in StandardHttpContextMap controller service.

By default it was set to 1 min.

[image]

Post increasing the value to 10 min , i was able to resolve that issue since my custom processors look more time to process the data.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Please ensure that you have configured an instance of `StandardHttpContextMap` controller service and referenced the same instance in the *HTTP Context Map* property for both of the `HandleHttpRequest` and `HandleHttpResponse` processors. This context map allows the flowfile to reference the HTTP context from the initial request when crafting the response.

Answer (score 1):

With my understanding on NIFI  since no code provided to identify exact problem, you are loosing HTTPResponse object somewhere during processing of the FlowFile in DataFlow.

Without code its hard to debug the issue

Comment: Thanks for the response. Would HTTPResponse object be present in the flowfile? Is there anyway to add the object into the flowfile.
Currently i am not handling any response object in my custom processor code.

Comment: I have mentioned change of missing it, but its can be in flowfile based on how you are making http requests and processing responses. Sorry we cant identify the exact problem without having exact code or configuraiton it would be great if you can share it